# Rollup summary field between multiple objects

Tags: lookup, master-detail, roll-up-summary, junction-object, rolluphelper

I have 4 objects: Contact, Attendee, Events, and Event Category. I want to create a rollup field on the Contact object to count total number of Events (where event category = Training) attended by Contact. The Contact and Event objects are related by a junction object called Attendee. See the image to better understand the task:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve the required results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard rollup fields work only with Master-Detail relationships - e.g. you could have a rollup field on your Event object summing up Attendee records for instance.

In your case I would probably look at using a Flow if you want a declarative approach (record triggered flow upon creation of Attendee record).

If you're happy writing apex then a trigger on the Attendee object that increments a count field on the Contact object would work as well.

In both situations you will have an Attendee record in your hands - you would filter on whether the Event is a 'training' event and if so, increment the field on the Contact object.

Comment: What I understand from this is 1) create a number field on contact 2) create a flow on attendee to update the number field on contact every time an event of type training is linked to it? right?

Comment: use DLRS to rollup over lookup relationships

Comment: @HariHa yes, that's what I meant.  Or as cropredy says, you can also install a rollup helper app from the AppExchange that overcomes the limitations of the standard rollup field.  If you think you'll regularly want to do rollups over lookups, this is a good idea.